# How to calculate total current drawn by a circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, batteries, integrated-circuit, frequency, current-measurement

[image: Simple Beacon]

I have been trying a make simple alarm using LM324 and a buzzer. The circuit is pretty simple. I need to power it from my 9V/1000mAH battery. But here is the part am stuck. I don't know how to calculate the total current consumed by the circuit. I need to know this in order to determine **how long i can run my alarm using the battery**. Here are the few specs i have gathered so far

1. Buzzer - 5mA at 9V
2. Output current or Source current of LM324 - 60mA

Now my question what exactly will be the current consumption of IC for this operation. Should i consider only the source current of IC as mentioned above or is there any other current parameters i should consider for making this total current drawn from the circuit calculation.

Somewhere i read that i should also take the account of Quiescent current into account. Is that so? Any guide that helps me to make this calculation please.

For the above setup output frequency will be around 20HZ. Should i take the output frequency into consideration for this calculation as well. Please any possible information will be much helpful.

P.S: Please feel free to edit this question if I haven't put it in the right way. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show specs for buzzer 5mA @9V . If these are true, that is the answer (plus current thru 2k@50%).  The circuit is a square wave with some dropout from supply rails in op amp.  CMOS Schmitt trigger would be louder. ( less drop)

Comment: Lead-acid cells are about 2.2 Volts, so I don't think you'll find a 9 Volt lead-acid battery.  6 and 12 Volt lead-acid batteries are common, and 8 volt ones exist.

Comment: This is the buzzer am talking about.  https://www.pololu.com/product/1260 . So you mean to say that my total current consumed will be  5mA + (8.3 / 2K @50%) = 7.075mA Am i doing this right? Please advice. I don't need to consider the Q-current of Op-amp IC?  @Peter Bennet Sorry wrong spec just 9V 1AH battery. Edited now.

Comment: Get ltspice and simulate.

Comment: @Andy aka Will try :) But am trying to figure it out manually for my learning purpose.  So as mentioned in my above comment   
Itotal = Ibuzzer + I (via R2 and R3) ,   
I through R2 and R3 = Vbat - 0.7v / 2k  @50% of duty cycle  , 
I = 9 - 0.7 / 2000 @ 50%   , 
I = 0.00415A or 4.15 mA @ 50%  
I = 4.15mA / 2   , 
I = 2.075mA , 

SO Itotal = 5mA + 2.075mA ?  , 

Am i doing it right please, any help will be much appreciated